# Make part of UIView visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I want to add a "shadow" image on my view, but, i want part of my view to still be "visible". You better understand what i want to do, when look on screenshot:[image]

I can add a `UIView` above my superview, but how could i make specific point "visible"? That actually mean make specific area of a view with different colour or opaque.

Comment: You can always add subviews...add subview and set its alpha to whatever you want...like in image attached you can add view with black color and suitable alpha and add add button and label on that...

Comment: Why don't you create your image with alpha components you need? Make the background color of your image more transparent with Photoshop _(or whatever painting program you use)_, then import it in Xcode.

Comment: @Crazyrems because i cant apply single image to all of screens (we have lot of iPhones and iPads)

Comment: You should use multiple views to your advantage. So far every answer suggested it :)

Comment: @Crazyrems what exactly you mean? If i add 0,5 alpha view above my superview, and then add another view above, it will still be above my 0,5 alpha shadow view. Sorry its not that clear for me

Comment: Maybe try to put your code or your view hierarchy to help us. How did you achieve what's on your screenshot ?

Comment: @Crazyrems its not achieved )) It is designer screen (what should be)

Comment: if i understood correctly....when first time user open that page ,u are trying to say user ,the functionality of button(why that button helps)..am i right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem I had a way, try the below example.

**1.  First storyboard design: I had a UIButton**

[image]

**2. Added black View as a subview**

```
    UIView *blackView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    blackView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    blackView.alpha=0.6f;
    [self.view addSubview:blackView];
```

now result will be:

[image]

**3. Add one more UIImageView with frame equal to button frame**

```
  UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
  imageView.frame=self.button.frame; //getting current UIButton bounds
  imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_img.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Now it looks same as what you want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Make a `UIView` called `buttonBackgroundView`, give it a black color and then

```
[self.view addsubView:buttonBackgroundView];
```

now make a `UIView` named `plusView` (or `UIButton` if this plus sign is a button) then

```
[self.view addsubView:plusView];
```

After that, give the alpha to the `buttonBackgroundView`

```
buttonBackgroundView.alpha = 0.6;
```

Happy coding!

Comment: i want part of my view to have specific alpha, not all of view

Comment: you want the plus to be compleely visible and the backround to be half visible like in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some views. A main view will be the container of your less-alpha view and of the opaque button.

```
MainView
   |
   ------- UIView with 0.6 alpha
   |
   ------- UIButton with 1 alpha
```

Indeed, if you change the alpha of the MainView, all subviews will be affected. Here, `UIView` with 0.6 will have the same frame as MainView but it will not affect `UIButton` alpha.

Comment: @Antonic C. My superview is alpha 1 and i need to add "Shadow" view with alpha 0,5 (for example), but with visible part of it.

Comment: If your using storyboard, try to drag your UIButton under the UIView with 0.6 alpha. Also verify that your button is not a subview of the transparent view.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new View, a parent View with clear color background. Add the black view and the button to the parent view and set the black view's alpha to 0.6 or whatever.